# How to combine thmmarks with addtag for \[\]?

Tags: equations, amsmath, theorems, ntheorem

I have the problem, that I have quite a few equations in my text. As I am oftenly unsure if I will need them later as a reference, I searched for a way to avoid exchanging `\[...\]` with and `equation` environment or similar.

I found the solution here in the answers that one can add the new command

```
\newcommand\addtag{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}}
```

to the preamble. SO far so good. Everything worked out correctly.

Now I wanted to enable `ntheorem` with `thmmarks` enabled. Now it seems, that the above command collides with the option. Here is a minimal (non)working example (Use one of the two inclusions for `ntheorem`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\addtag{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}}
% \usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{Proof}{Proof}
\begin{document}
\begin{Proof}
We assume weknow the solution. Thus we know it.
\end{Proof}

An equation
\[ a = b + c. \addtag \]
\end{document}
```

I see several possibilities:

- Find some way to modify the `\addtag` macro such that it is compatible; here I do not know where to start. Maybe you can give me a hint....
- Replace the needed `\[...\]` by `equation` environments.
- Replace all `\[...\]` by `equation` environmants and using `mathtools` to get the numbering correct.

For the last two options I do not know if it will work with `ntheorem` for all cases. So if you know there are issues, please let me know before I replace all my texts.

Edit: I just experimented with my MWE and mathtools. Unfortunately the equation counters gets a bit messed up. With `empheq` it seems (!) to work but only tested at MWE. Here is the [modified version using `empheq`](http://pastebin.com/J4sfLNFm).

Comment: I think it's easier using `equation*` and `equation`.

Comment: Use `equation` all the time, and load the `autonum` package if you don't want to keep track of which equations are supposed to be numbered.

Comment: Instead of  defining \addtag to be used with the \[...\] construct, you could just as well use \notag (which is already defined) within the equation environment.

Comment: Forgotten: there's also the showonlyrefs of the mathtools package (see § 3.2 of the doc).

Comment: @Bernard This is quite a mess to change the command/add `notag`s for a few hundred equations. `mathtools` does not behave well in conjuncton with `ntheorem`. In a small test it was not compiling or with many bugs. Not so nice... But though, thnaks

Comment: Oh !! I see… There's a caveat concerning ntheorem and mathtools: any modification to the appearance of tags should be done after ntheorem has been loaded. So maybe it's wiser to load math tools after ntheorem.

Comment: It is just the tag appearance that has to be done after ntheorem (ntheorem messes with it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last thing that `amsmath` (or `mathtools`) does is to set `\[...\]` to be `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}`.  Now `thmtools` patches `equation*` to work with `thmmarks`, but it also redefines `\[...\]`.  So the simplest solution is to reassert the ams aliasing:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\addtag{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}}

\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{Proof}{Proof}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Proof}
  Use induction on~\( j \).
\end{Proof}

An equation
\[ a = b + c. \addtag \]

\end{document}
```